# Why does [my_document].save result in a 'collection already exists'; code: '48'?

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

When I run `[my_document].save` the **first time** it runs no problem, creates the collection and saves the document.

When I run it the **second time** (and any subsequent times), I receive the error `'collection already exists'; code: '48'`.

I am running `mongo 3.2.0` and `mongoid 2.4.7`.

If I run `db.dropDatabase();` in the mongo console, then I can run it again without trouble...but **just once**. After that, it won't work at all.

I can also delete the `tmp/mongodb/[my_collection]` directory manually, and it works again...**just once**, and not again.

I've run `brew uninstall mongodb` and `brew install mongodb` more than once to no avail; same behavior.

Rather frustrating. Of course the collection exists. It should exist. And it shouldn't be a problem. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Alright. I've solved it. Has to do with the mongoid version. I'll post a proper answer here soon.

Comment: Hi, I've the same problem. Can you post your solution? Thx.